# Programmatically setup headerviews

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know how to add headers to UICollectionViews however I don't know how to customize them. The method I know is similar to customizing UICollectionViewCells however I probably am missing a few subclasses and some required setup code, because when I cast my header as this class it fails...

```
class LiveHeader: UICollectionReusableView {


}
```

There has to be some required initialization code or something but I haven't found any examples online. Most do this using storyboards.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

```
//reuse identifier.

let LiveHeaderId = "LiveHeaderId"

//viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCollectionView()

    //Register Headers
    collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: LiveHeaderId)
    //Register Cells
    collectionView?.register(LiveCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: LiveCellId)

}
```

Here is where I setup the header view

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let liveHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: LiveHeaderId, for: indexPath) as! LiveHeader
    liveHeader.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    /*
    //Here I ended up creating the view because I couldn't get the cast to work. This is my opinion clutters ups the code especially because I eventually want to register more headers
    let container: UIView = {
        let c = UIView()
        c.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        c.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return c

    }()

    let labelContainer: UIView = {
        let lc = UIView()
        lc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//            lc.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 168/255, green: 250/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        lc.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 77/255, green: 182/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 1)
        lc.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return lc
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.text = "LIVE"
        l.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        l.textAlignment = .center
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.textColor = UIColor.white
        return l
    }()

    liveHeader.addSubview(container)
    liveHeader.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: container)
    liveHeader.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: container)


    container.addSubview(labelContainer)
    labelContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.1).isActive = true
    labelContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    labelContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: labelContainer, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.25, constant: 0).isActive = true


    labelContainer.addSubview(label)
    labelContainer.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: label)
    labelContainer.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: label)



    return liveHeader
} */


//header size

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height / 16)
}
```

If anything I believe I might be missing something in my 'viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as you implement custom `UIView`'s.

```
import UIKit

class MyHeaderCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

    var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.custom(title: "Title", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 20), titleColor: .black, textAlignment: .center, numberOfLines: 1)
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension MyHeaderCollectionReusableView : ViewSetable {

    func setupViews() {
        autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        backgroundColor = .white
        addSubview(titleLabel)
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        // Title label constraints.
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension UILabel {

    func custom(title: String, font: UIFont, titleColor: UIColor, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment, numberOfLines: Int) {
        self.text = title
        self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        self.font = font
        self.textColor = titleColor
        self.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }


/// Defines methods for creating view.
protocol ViewSetable {

    /// Creates view hierarchy.
    func setupViews()

    /// Creates anchors between views.
    func setupConstraints()
}
```

The example present `UICollectionView` header with title label which match the whole space of the given header height.

**Edit**

As you registe header you can not register it via :

```
collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: LiveHeaderId)
```

Change it to:

```
collectionView?.register(YOUR_HEADER_CLASS.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: YOUR_REUSE_ID)
```

It should solve your problems!

Comment: my cast is still failing. The debugger says Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' which is odd because the cast is in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` I will post the code in the question.

Comment: Did you register the header for collection ?

Comment: That is pretty werid behavior. Show me how did you register it.

Comment: Did that solve your problem ? Make sure to accept the answer ! Thanks.